PowerShell Convert to secure string not working
When I user either of the code examples below I get an error message that the password I use is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, or operable condition.
I am using a domain username and password, and the account has admin privileges.
1st attempt
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential username,(‘password’ | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)

2nd attempt
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential domain\username,(‘password’ | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)

I expected the username and password to be accepted but it is not accepting the password.
I am using the code above to join a system to the domain.

Given the description of your error, the likeliest explanation is that your script file is misinterpreted by the Windows PowerShell engine, which happens if the script is saved as UTF-8 without a BOM (this is no longer a problem in PowerShell (Core) 7+). Try saving your script as UTF-8 with BOM. See this answer for more information. If this solves your problem, we can close your question as a duplicate.

Specifically, the ‘ characters around password would cause the problem if the file isn't recognized as UTF-8 encoded by Windows PowerShell. While switching to UTF-8 with BOM solves that problem, it's generally better to stick with ASCII-range punctuation, i.e. the ' single quote (apostrophe).

Trying to resolve this, but as I am new to this, I am having an issue as I cannot find the settings.json file.

Open your Visual Studio Code settings.json file for editing as follows: From the command palette (select menu command View > Command Palette... or press Ctrl+Shift+P to open it), select command Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON); searching for user json should be enough to locate it.

Also note that you can fix this on a per-file basis: With the file of interest open, click on UTF-8 In the status bar near the right edge, then choose Save with Encoding and select UTF-8 with BOM.

I did not have Visual Studio Code installed so I had to install it on my system.  Then I made the change to UTF-8 with BOM.  I opened my PowerShell script in Visual Studio Code and the saved it and then closed it.  When I reopened the PowerShell script it showed UTF-8 with BOM on the bottom right of the screen.  However, when I run the PowerShell script, I still get the same error message.

Note that using Visual Studio Code, specifically, isn't necessary - any modern editor should be able to re-save a with as UTF-8 with BOM. I assumed you were already using Visual Studio Code, since you asked about settings.json (I was hoping that it's clear from the linked answer that using Visual Studio Code was just one way to fix the problem, with the settings.json method fixing it also for future files.)

If you still get the same error, then there's either still a character-encoding problem, or your file contains invisible control characters - without additional information, your problem cannot be diagnosed. The commands shown in your question work just fine, if there's no character-encoding problem, as copying and pasting them into an interactive session will show you.

Just stop using those curly quotes in code and use straight ones ‘password’ --> 'password'
